# GNU gettext or alternatives for tex files

Tags: languages, translate

I have a document that I want in two different versions, and the difference being the language only. [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) is a way of achieving this, but I am unsure about how to get this to work for LaTeX/Tex files. Do anyone have any experience with this?

I am aware of `ifthen` and `\newcommand`, but it's getting a bit messy.

Comment: @Marijn I am aware of the solutions in that question, but I am asking for a different way to do it. Without writing anything extra in the document. I want to use gettext or some equivalent program.

Comment: May have found something. https://github.com/mquinson/po4a

Comment: Interesting, if you find out that this tool works then it would be good to write an answer about it. However, that would preferably be an additional answer to the other question, since they are IMO very close duplicates (the other question also mentions `gettext`), so that this question can be closed and everything about this topic is in one place.

Comment: Okey, I will do that after I have tested it @Marijn.